# Issues with setw in c++

Tags: c++, setw

Hi first here is my program  i want to make all the output of my program is segregate in column

Here is the Output of my program right now i want to make the output is all line in in age and section:

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct student {
string fullname[200];
string  course[200];
int age[200];
};
student p1;
main()
{
    int input;
    cout<<"How many Student do you like to Add:";
    cin>>input;
    for(int i=0; i!=input; i++)
    {
        cout<<"----------Input #"<<i+1<<"----------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline (cin,p1.fullname[i]);
        cout<<"Enter Age: ";
        cin>>p1.age[i];
        cout<<"Enter Section: ";
        cin>>p1.course[i];
    }

    cout<<"\n\n----------------- List of Student that is 19 Above -----------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nFull Name:"<<setw(20)<<"Age:"<<setw(20)<<"Section:"<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i!=input; i++)
    {
        if(p1.age[i] >= 19)
        {
        cout<<p1.fullname[i]<< setfill(' ') <<setw(20) <<p1.age[i]<< setfill(' ') <<setw(20)<<p1.course[i]<<endl;       
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `setfill` and `setw` before the field that you want to write. And you need to apply it also to `fullname`.

```
cout << setfill(' ')
     << setw(20) << p1.fullname[i]
     << setw(20) << p1.age[i]
     << setw(20) << p1.course[i]
     << endl;
```

Comment: `setfill` only needs to be applied once if the fill character is unchanged

Comment: @M.M Good point. In my answer I just copy-pasted the original code, thus the double setfill. I reduced it to one `setfill` only now.